# Instanciar prefabs unity

Tags: c#, unity

Estoy generando prefabs de acuerdo a información obtenida de una base de datos... El tema es que dentro de ese prefabs hay un texto el cual accedo a él a través de un script.. Con el propósito de cambiar ese texto por la información de la bd. El problema es que solo me cambia el primer prefabs(Lo que es obvio por el find) Cómo podría realizarlo de mejor manera??? He intentado de varias formas pero sin éxito.

Esto es lo que tengo

```
foreach (string p in ListArtist)
{
        instancia  = Instantiate(grid, transform.position, transform.rotation, padre.transform);
        hijo = GameObject.Find("name_artist");
        hijo.GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.Text>().text = p;
}
```

Comment: para que se usa `instancia` en el codigo que nos muestras?

Comment: En realidad para nada, lo acabo de sacar.. estaba probando algo hace un rato y quedo así pero en verdad no tiene relevancia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al final aplique lo siguiente

```
foreach (string p in ListArtist)
    {
        Instantiate(grid, transform.position, transform.rotation, padre.transform);
        gameobects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("name_artist");
        foreach(GameObject ob in gameobects){

        ob.GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.Text>().text = p;
```

Answer (score 1):

Analizando la documentacion

[GameObject.Find()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.Find.html)

menciona:

> This function only returns active GameObjects. If no GameObject with name can be found, null is returned. If name contains a '/' character, it traverses the hierarchy like a path name.

o sea que solo retorna un objeto activo con ese nombre, si buscas siempre con el mismo nombres obtendras el mismo objeto.

Deberias buscas diferentes nombres para asignarles los textos que iteras